# Благодарность ответившему репутацией, если не назначен конкурс

Tags: поддержка, репутация

Иногда хочется поблагодарить за подробные исчерпывающие ответы, на которые было потрачено немало времени и усилий, не только плюсом и галочкой. Можно ли отписать ответившему баллы своей репутации, если конкурс не был назначен?

Comment: можно назначить конкурс и поставить на этот ответ

Comment: Да, даже если ответ принят, можно начать конкурс. Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @СашаЧерных а мой ответ вам показался недостойным награды? ;)

Comment: @PashaPash, какой именно?

Comment: @СашаЧерных в вопросе про EF. Если серьезно - синяя отметка награды на ответе привлекает внимание гораздо сильнее, чем стандартный зеленый чекбокс. Так что с ней стоит быть осторожнее в случае, если ответы предполагают разный подход к решению проблемы.

Comment: @PashaPash, [этому ответу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/507901/199934) не я назначил 25 баллов. У меня почему-то избранный ответ с дополнительной добавленной к нему репутацией появился в очереди проверок — и я отредактировал в нём мелкие ошибки. Видимо, баг какой-то.

Comment: @СашаЧерных ок, нашел - это был первый ответ от этого пользователя (точнее, ловушка в очереди проверок). но пожелание все равно в силе - осторожнее с прямыми наградами :)

Comment: @PashaPash, в очереди сообщений от новых участников. Когда я редактировал ответ, у ув-мого Alexcei Shmakov показывалась репутация в 1 балл.

Comment: @СашаЧерных это был аудит - проверка на внимательность - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/75775. Не знал, что правки из аудита принимаются напрямую.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Разумеется можно. Специально для этого есть одна из опций при объявлении конкурса:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Иначе чем через конкурс *передать* репутацию нельзя.

Напрашивается способ "наплюсовать все вопросы и ответы этого участника". Но этот способ плох по следующим причинам:

1. Награждается не конкретный ответ, а участник в целом. Его ответы получат голоса за просто так, а не за их качество. Где-то из-за этого менее хороший ответ будет оценен лучше соседних.
2. Если голосовать сразу много за одного участника, система аннулирует голоса. Это событие журналируется и о нем известно модераторам.
3. Если голосовать каждый день понемногу, то факт накрутки голосов всё равно будет замечен модераторами, только немного позже. В результате голоса всё равно будут аннулированы — не только отданные "в награду", но и вообще все голоса участника А за сообщения участника Б.

Comment: можно пройтись по всем ответам/вопросам юзера и проплюсовать :)

Comment: @Grundy не сработает, система откатит голоса.

Comment: Сколько раз можно плюсануть, чтобы система не откатила голоса?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, это если сразу много  за мелкий промежуток.  :-)

Comment: @СашаЧерных плюсовать - плохой способ. Лучше наградите конкретный ответ с помощью конкурса.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, при плюсовании своя репутация не расходуется :)

Comment: @Grundy а если понемногу и регулярно, то придёт модератор и будет задавать вопросы насчет накрутки голосов. =)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, а если модератор в доле? ;-)

Comment: А на ламповом ХэшКоде можно было и без конкурса репой одаривать)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб наверняка в процессе миграции все подарки откатились. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, да я и не против) Значит мне +15 репы прилететь должно было при переезде)))

Comment: *Если голосовать каждый день понемногу, то факт накрутки голосов всё равно будет замечен модераторами, только немного позже* — при «разборе группы b» я регулярно голосую за ответы одних и тех же авторов. вам (модераторам) приходят оповещения и о моих голосах в этой «группе b»? кстати, а если движок посчитает какие-нибудь мои голоса накруткой, я хоть узнаю о том, что эти голоса «откатились»?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin конечно, это не единственный критерий. Все высокореповые участники много раз голосовали друг за друга и ничего странного или нечестного в этом нет. :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, и всё-таки: про «откаты» голосов движок сообщает?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin не оповещает, но позволяет узнать постфактум.

Comment: Кстати, а если наоборот участнику за небольшой отрезок времени поставили много минусов, а не плюсов, это как-то заметно для системы? Кто-то сейчас отминусил мои вопросы/ответы, причём у всех их — разная тематика. Возможно, репутацию изменяли *участнику*, а не *сообщениям*.

Comment: @СашаЧерных если система определит это как умышленное голосование против участника, то откатит.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin перечитывал этот диалог, на всякий случай проверил. Несмотря на то, что вы много голосуете за, нет ни одного участника, за сообщения которого вы бы отдали существенную долю голосов.