# Можно ли разделить награду за конкурс?

Tags: поддержка

С месяц назад [задавал я вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/551847/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-git-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/559920#559920) на stackoverflow -- и получил два ответа, каждый из которых мне помог потом подобрать итоговое решение.

И что-то мне показалось мало поставить каждому по одному upvote -- решил открыть конкурс и добавить из своей репутации.

Только вот никогда не создавал конкурсы, поэтому не понимаю: движок позволит мне разделить награду между несколькими ответами или я должен всю награду на одного человека назначить?

Читал [справку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), там этот вопрос обошли стороной. На мете тоже особо ничего не нашлось, кроме [одного вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2875/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81) из которого я понял только то, что мне не обязательно снимать галку со своего вопроса, чтобы начать конкурс.

Answer (score 10):

Насколько понимаю, по окончании конкурса можно назначить ещё одну награду, чтобы выдать её второму герою или чтобы увеличить награду для первого.

> [Могу ли я назначить награду за два ответа?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252021/)
> Да, вы можете наградить два ответа.
>
> [Как работает система наград?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/)
> В одном вопросе вы можете назначить столько наград, сколько хотите. Учтите, одновременно назначать несколько наград нельзя – только одна награда может быть активной в промежуток времени. Один участник одновременно может иметь не более трех открытых конкурсов.

Но каждую следующую награду придётся делать [как минимум вдвое больше](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105639/330339):

> На данный момент мы просим удваивать новую награду в вопросах с завершенным успешным конкурсом. Таким образом, если предыдущая награда равнялась 50 баллам репутации, то следующая награда в том же вопросе должна быть не менее 100 баллов.

Comment: А где предупреждение про удвоение суммы награды?

Comment: @Qwertiy Спасибо за замечание. Дополнил ответ.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky Небольшое замечание. Вы постоянно цитируете англоязычную версию, но вообще основной язык сайта -- русский. Про удвоение точно можно заменить на русскую ссылку:  http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

Comment: @А.К. К сожалению, понял русскую версию только после того, как прочёл английскую :) Свой перевод не готов предложить, потому что не до конца понимаю тонкости системы и боюсь приплести лишнего. Поэтому подкрепляющие цитаты - на языке оригинала.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Спасибо за перевод и за новое [подробное объяснение про конкурсы](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3618/)!