# Переработка конкурса для дополнительной награды

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, репутация, конкурс

Предлагаю переработать систему конкурсов **для вручения дополнительной награды**.

---

В текущей системе меня не устраивает следующее:

- Ожидание перед назначением конкурса
- Ожидание перед награждением ответа
- Увеличение последующих наград

Ты получаешь ответ на свой вопрос, ждёшь, когда пройдёт 48 часов с момента публикации, назначаешь конкурс, ждёшь 24 часа и наконец награждаешь ответ.

Для меня это выглядит примерно так:

> Мне дарят подарок, который я очень хочу. Я просто киваю и ухожу.
>   *Спустя 2 дня:*
>   "Привет! Ты мне подарил подарок позавчера. Перезвоню поблагодарить
>   завтра"
>   *Спустя ещё 24 часа:*
>   "Привет! Чудесный подарок, большое тебе спасибо!"

Странно, правда? Я хотел бы показать свою благодарность здесь и сейчас, чтобы отвечающему было приятно (o･ω･o).

Но суммарные задержки настолько велики, что о вопросе\ответе можно попросту забыть, а потом удивиться внезапной репутации.

Также непонятно, что делать с награждением нескольких ответов. У меня лично ещё не было такой ситуации, но подобный вопрос я уже [видел](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3593/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81).

Ещё можно сказать о том, что данный вопрос висит 24 часа в конкурсных. Но зачем? Ответ ведь уже есть. Он только отвлекает внимание других.

---

Справка о конкурсах *([1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty))* говорит нам следующее:

> #### Все ли вопросы подходят для объявления конкурса?
>
> Если у
>   вопроса отсутствует кнопка объявления конкурса, возможно, причина
>   (причины) в следующем:
>
> 1. Вопрос был задан в течение последних 48 часов. Сперва дайте
>      сообществу шанс ответить в обычном порядке.

Мне кажется, что если ответ уже имеет исчерпывающее решение, то, при переработке, правила не будут нарушены, так как *сообщество воспользовалось шансом ответить в обычном порядке.* Система отработала.

---

Предлагаю следующее:

- Отменить задержку перед назначением конкурса, если он призван дополнительно наградить ответ.
- Отменить задержку перед награждением за такой конкурс, то есть вручать награду моментально.
- Отменить увеличение последующих наград за такой конкурс, чтобы можно было наградить одинаковым количеством репутации несколько ответов.

Это, на мой взгляд, более интуитивная и понятная система.

---

Очень хотелось бы услышать ваши комментарии по моим предложениям.

Кстати, насколько вообще возможны такие изменения?
Может, вопрос стоит разместить на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: Проблема в том, что система конкурсов может быть использована для искусственного увеличения репутации марионеток, поэтому передача наград требует дополнительного внимания сообщества. См. например https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318499/8674428

Comment: `...показать свою благодарность..., чтобы отвечающему было приятно`. Следующая стадия: узаконенные лайки/дизлайки, репосты, добавление в друзья. В моем понимании: ответ может быть полезным/бесполезным, и являться решением для автора вопроса.

Comment: «Также непонятно, что делать с награждением нескольких ответов» — ничего особенного, открываете несколько конкурсов по очереди. Вот тут я три награды раздал за три недели https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/581668/181472

Comment: По поводу ожидания двух дней до начала конкурса [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5119/176217).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Награда привлекает к ответу внимание, которое приносит ещё голоса за ответ и комментарии к нему. А ещё, бывает, появляются новые ответы с другими способами решения. Автору оригинального ответа может быть интересно их читать.

Оставляя конкурс на максимальный срок вы дарите внимание. Имхо, это более ценный подарок, чем репутация.

---

Когда на вопросе открыт конкурс, такой вопрос нельзя закрыть или удалить, а отменить конкурс могут только модераторы. Если можно будет открывать конкурс сразу, получится незакрываемый вопрос, и это эксплоит. Поэтому в первые 48 часов после публикации вопроса конкурс открывать нельзя. Предполагается, что откровенно плохой вопрос за это время либо улучшат, либо закроют.

> Мне кажется, что если ответ уже имеет исчерпывающее решение, то, при переработке, правила не будут нарушены

Это сложно определить программно. Ни рейтинг ответа, ни зелёная галочка не гарантируют, что решение исчерпывающее или вообще работающее.

Comment: Модераторы - часть сообщества. По крайней мере, я так всегда думал.

Comment: Неужели модераторы не могут удалить конкурсный вопрос?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ часть, да. Смысл в том что вопрос нельзя закрыть без модератора.

Comment: @nomnoms12 технически — модератор может отменить конкурс. Но это всегда непростое решение, и нужно разбираться в теме вопроса. Модераторы вроде как не для этого.

Answer (score 4):

А что если ответ есть, но он плохой?

Предполагается, что за то время, пока вопрос висит в конкурсных, на него смогут дать ответы лучше или указать на косяки имеющихся ответов.