# Почему нельзя закрывать "конкурсные" вопросы и нужно ли?

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов, конкурс

К чему такая защита? Нельзя ли просто "заморозить" срок награды и возобновить отсчёт, когда его переоткроют?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5119/181472

Comment: И ещё https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9359/181472

Answer (score 2):

Конкурс можно объявить только через двое суток после публикации вопроса. Если вопрос так уж плох, то стоило уложиться в эти двое суток и закрыть раньше.

Если пользователь сделал какие-то махинации с вопросом прежде чем объявить конкурс (сразу удалил, а через 2 дня восстановил; либо полностью переписал старый вопрос), можно ставить тревогу для модератора, который сможет отменить конкурс и закрыть вопрос.

Comment: Бывают вопросы из не самых посещаемых меток, например.